# kendo Grid - Sub column values got wrongly mapped when reordering the Column

Tags: kendo-ui-grid

Here below link for code
http://dojo.telerik.com/AguGO/2

1) Drag the column header "Ship Address" along with its sub columns to two columns before.
2) After dragging is done, the sub column values are wrongly placed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LACck.png)